# Show/hide divs based on dropdown selection with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using rails to generate a form that allows users to add instances of a form using an add button. Each instance of the form is wrapped in a div tag with a class of "fields". I would like to use JS to show and hide divs within each form instance.

I'm struggling to find out why none of my JS is working properly.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LfezLv4b/2/)

```
# Structure of my HTML
<form>
    <div class="fields">
        <select class="type">
            <option value="business">Business</option>
            <option value="personal">Personal</option>
        </select>
        <div id="personal">
            <p>Business fields</p>
        </div>
        <div id="business">
            <p>personal fields</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fields">
        <select class="type">
            <option value="business">Business</option>
            <option value="personal">Personal</option>
        </select>
        <div id="personal">
            <p>Business fields</p>
        </div>
        <div id="business">
             <p>personal fields</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

# JS
$(function () {
  $(".fields").each(function() {
    $("#personal").hide();
    $("#business").hide();
    $('.type').on('change', function () {
      if (this.value === 'business'){
        $("#business").show();
      } else {
        $("#personal").hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You cannot use the same `id` twice on an HTML page.

Comment: `#personal` & `#business` need to be classes, not IDs, are they are not unique.

Comment: OK updating question now. However, even with those changes even the hide() methods aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
$(".fields div:not(.business)").hide();

$('.type').on('change', function () {
    var x = this.value;
    $(this).siblings('div').not('.'+x).hide().siblings('.'+x).show();
});
```

*By the way, your `.personal` divs contain "Business" and vice versa. **Please set that correctly** for the code to work.*


#### *JS Fiddle Demo*